# Kloosterman sums in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request

Define the Kloosterman sum

$$K(m, n, c) := \sum_{d \hspace{1ex}(\hspace{-1.2ex}\mod\hspace{-.5ex} c)^{*}} e^{\frac{2\pi i (nd + m\overline{d})}{c}},$$

where $d \hspace{1ex}(\hspace{-1.2ex}\mod\hspace{-.5ex} c)^{*}$ runs through those primitive $d$ coprime to $c$, and where $\overline{d}$ is the inverse of $d$ modulo $c$. I want to find what conditions on $m, n, c$, if any, make $K(m, n, c)$ a $p$-rational number. That is, I want to find out when $K(m, n, c) \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. Is there any literature on this? I have no success so far in Googling. At least a little push in the right direction could help :-)

Comment: It is an algebraic integer